# gdb debugging with openocd on codeblocks IDE

Tags: gdb, codeblocks, gdbserver, openocd

I have recently started working on Gdb with openOCD for ARM Development on Codeblocks IDE. There are two commands in gdb like "**load** ./bin/Debug/ledtest.elf", "**file** ./bin/Debug/ledtest.elf" which will result in writing the program to flash and debugging.

My problem is whenever I am using these commands, its not writing into flash. I don't know how to make my ecosystem to do that? Whether I have to make relevent changes in gdb or openocd?
However when I try to **flash_write** from openocd, it works fine.
Any idea? Any relevant document will be helpful.

Comment: If anyone knows, tell me what are the sequence of commands took into the backend on flash when someone wrote "load ./bin/Debug/ledtest.elf".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still have this problem, but anyway for completness:

I use this in my gdb debugger startup in codeblocks:

---

```
monitor reset halt

file Output/firmware.elf

mon flash write_image erase Output/firmware.elf

monitor halt
```

---

the flash command erases only the segments which are necessary for the firmware.

Comment: Thanks for reply, 
But whenever, I uses 'monitor reset halt' it gives me the error 'ocd_bouncer'. Do you have any idea, what could be the reason?